# Configuration to an binding using soap 1.2 in a WCF Project to be consumed for a non C# client

Tags: c#, wcf, soap

i have study and read about it a little, but i can't do this yet so i post this question.
Here is my binding configuration:

`<bindings>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="httpSoap12">
          <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12"/>
          <httpTransport />
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="Service.OnOffService">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress = "http://192.168.0.14:5554/Service/OnOffService" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address="soap12" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="httpSoap12" contract="Service.IOnOffService">`

and this is my contract:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://testeService")]
public interface IOnOffService
{
    [OperationContract]
    string OnOff(string Usuario);
}
```

and here i build the Envelope to consume this service:

```
sEnv = sEnv & "<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=""http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-   envelope"" xmlns:tem=""http://testeService/"">"
sEnv = sEnv & "  <soap:Header xmlns:wsa=""http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"">"
sEnv = sEnv & "     <wsa:Action>http://testeService/IOnOffService/OnOff</wsa:Action>"
sEnv = sEnv & "     <wsa:To>http://192.168.0.14:5554/Service/OnOffService</wsa:To>"
sEnv = sEnv & "  </soap:Header>"
sEnv = sEnv & "  <soap:Body>"
sEnv = sEnv & "    <tem:OnOff>"
sEnv = sEnv & "      <tem:Usuario>A</tem:Usuario>"
sEnv = sEnv & "    </tem:OnOff>"
sEnv = sEnv & "  </soap:Body>"
sEnv = sEnv & "</soap:Envelope>"
```

the problem is, i've received a 400 bad request error....

Comment: You have a space in the URI for the `xmlns:soap` namespace - `"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-   envelope"` - was that a typo?  If not, it should be `xmlns:soap=""http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope""`, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must binding="basicHttpBinding" on endpoint.

App.config of my project .

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfServiceLibrary1.Service1">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress = "http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfServiceLibrary1/Service1/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <!-- Service Endpoints -->
        <!-- Unless fully qualified, address is relative to base address supplied above -->
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WcfServiceLibrary1.IService1">
          <!-- 
              Upon deployment, the following identity element should be removed or replaced to reflect the 
              identity under which the deployed service runs.  If removed, WCF will infer an appropriate identity 
              automatically.
          -->
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <!-- Metadata Endpoints -->
        <!-- The Metadata Exchange endpoint is used by the service to describe itself to clients. --> 
        <!-- This endpoint does not use a secure binding and should be secured or removed before deployment -->
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
          set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="True"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
          set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
          to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

Also you can look my web site about soap but my web is turkish . There are codes in there . [cihanasan.com](http://cihanasan.com/2015/06/13/net-soap-ile-xml-kullanimi/)